# Boundary Condition for Generating Evanescent Waves

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I'm reading through Novotny and Hecht's book on Nano-Optics (Principles of Nano-Optics), and I've come across a subtlety in the boundary conditions for evanescent wave generation (via total internal reflection) that I don't understand.

In the 2nd edition of the book the equation I'm struggling with is labelled 2.104, but exactly the same content is available online [here](http://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/optics/Courses/NanoOptics/foundations.pdf) where it's labelled 2.91.

My question is this: where does the negative sign come from in the x component of the transmitted field $\textbf{E}_2$? I understand that the parallel components of the electric field must be conserved across the boundary, but where does the factor of $-1$ arise?

Many thanks!